# Split each row into multiple rows merging columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Updating my question to make it clearer. 
I have a CSV file that has multiple columns/rows.
I read it like this

```
in_csv = pd.read_csv(inputFileName.csv)
```

To be general enough, the columns are in this format

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,JK,KK,...,Def1, Def_1x,Def_1y,Def2,Def_2x,Def_2y
```

Some rows have values in `Def1`, `Def_1x`, `Def_1y`, `Def2`, `Def_2x`, `Def_2y`. other rows have values only in `Def1`, `Def_1x`, `Def_1y`.
I want to output in another csv as follows:

1. New rows have columns `Col1,Col2,Col3,JK,KK,...,Def1,Def_1x,Def_1y` (no `Def2`, `Def_2x`, `Def_2y`)
2. If `row_i` in input csv has NO values in `Def_2x`, `Def_2y`, then same row is copied in output csv (without the last three cols)
3. If `row_j` in input csv has values in `Def_2x`, `Def_2y`, then split it into two rows in output csv. One row with `Def1`, `Def_1x`, `Def_1y` and a second one with values in `Def2`, `Def_2x`, `Def_2y` copied to `Def1`, `Def_1x`, `Def_1y` of output csv
4. after splitting a row into two rows, keep the same row order
5. Rows with all last 6 columns empty, stay as is

Example input:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,JK,KK,...,Def1, Def_1x,Def_1y,Def2,Def_2x,Def_2y
A1,B1,C1,....,a,0.2,0.3,,,
A2,B2,C2,.....,b,0.4,0.5,b,0.6,0.7
A3,B3,C3,.....,b,0.8,0.9,,,
A4,B4,C4,.....,,,,,,
```

Expected output:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,JK,KK,...,Def1, Def_1x,Def_1y
A1,B1,C1,....,a,0.2,0.3
A2,B2,C2,.....,b,0.4,0.5
A2,B2,C2,.....,b,0.6,0.7
A3,B3,C3,.....,b,0.8,0.9
A4,B4,C4,.....,,,
```

Order of the rows is the same `A1`, `A2`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`. Once a row is split, the copy comes right below, not at the bottom of the csv.

If I can have another column added (`RANK`) like below, it would be a bonus much appreciated. It is basically always 1 for rows non split. and 1:2 for rows split into two rows.

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,JK,KK,...,RANK,Def1, Def_1x,Def_1y
A1,B1,C1,....,1,a,0.2,0.3
A2,B2,C2,.....,1,b,0.4,0.5
A2,B2,C2,.....,2,b,0.6,0.7
A3,B3,C3,.....,1,b,0.8,0.9
A4,B4,C4,.....,,,,
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to python as mentioned above, All I did was reading the input csv using pd.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to stack the `X` and `Y` entries.

With `df` as a Pandas data frame:

```
  Col1 Col2   X1   X2   Y1   Y2
0   A1   B1  0.2  0.3  NaN  NaN
1   A2   B2  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
```

Separate the `X` and `Y` entries, then `concat()`:

```
y_cols = ['Y1','Y2']
x_cols = ['X1','X2']
non_y_cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(y_cols)]
non_x_cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(x_cols)]
pd.concat([df[non_y_cols], 
           df[non_x_cols].dropna().rename(columns={'Y1':'X1','Y2':'X2'})])

  Col1 Col2   X1   X2
0   A1   B1  0.2  0.3
1   A2   B2  0.4  0.5
1   A2   B2  0.6  0.7
```

Comment: third column of your piece of code errors out saying "IndexError: too many indices for array". My csv has actually 22 columns and 155 rows.
I am using your script after I replaced df with the variable returned from reading the csv file with pd.read_csv. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean the third row of my code?  The `non_y_cols` assignment?  Can you confirm that the code works with the example data you provided originally?  I just added on a few extra columns and rows to your example data, and I'm not getting an error.

Comment: Yes, I meant third row. Sorry!
This is my code:
in_csv_dt = pd.read_csv(csvFileName)
then your code using in_csv_dt instead of df, for example: non_x_cols=in_csv_dt.columns[~in_csv_dt.columns.isin(x_cols)] etc. 
I can check the code on the example above on spider editor to see .

Comment: It sounds like there may be an edge case in your actual data that is unaccounted for in the example data you provided.  Providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really valuable - sometimes just doing that helps me reason through a problem and identify edge cases.  Consider updating your original post with a representative MCVE if these solutions aren't working for your actual data.  (Does John Galt's solution work?)

Comment: I tried the same data above and it shows the same issue. Actually I think that is because ~in_dcv_dt.isin(y_cols) is not returning what is expected. This is its output (all true)

   Col1  Col2    X1    X2    Y1    Y2
0  True  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True  True

Comment: `isin()` should be applied to the data frame's *columns*.  `df.columns.isin(y_cols)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach

```
In [1580]: pd.concat(
             [df.loc[:,cols.str.contains(p)]
                .rename(columns={'Y1':'X1','Y2':'X2'})
                .dropna() for p in ['Col|X', 'Col|Y']],
             ignore_index=True)
Out[1580]:
  Col1 Col2   X1   X2
0   A1   B1  0.2  0.3
1   A2   B2  0.4  0.5
2   A2   B2  0.6  0.7
```

Comment: Thanks Galt. How can I generalize this if, I have multiple other columns in between the first and the X/Y. I tried to make the example above simple, sorry about that.

Col1, Col2, AB, XX, YY, JK, X1,X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Y3

A1,B1,....,0.2,0.3,a,,,

A2,B2,.....,0.4,0.5,b,0.6,0.7,b

Output expected as initially, keep all columns from Col1 ...to JK. Then 

[Y1,Y2,Y3] -> [X1,X3,X3]

So basically how to generalize this:  p in ['Col|X', 'Col|Y']